# Overtones(?) seem to be showing up in FFT of audio signal

Tags: audio, fft, teensy

I am processing audio data using a Teensy 3.2. I have a microphone attached to it, and am playing music in my room using some powerful speakers.

When I look at data from the Fourier Transform of the audio data (specifically, the 1024 point fft [from the teensy audio library](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/gui/index.html?info=AudioAnalyzeFFT1024)), there appear to be overtones showing up when I don't expect them to. For example, when I play a pure middle C tone (263 Hz), the corresponding frequency bins return about .6 amplitude, but the frequency bins corresponding to 700-800hz also light up at about .2 amplitude. Some higher frequencies also light up at lower amplitudes. This is unexpected, as I am just playing a 263Hz sine wave through a frequency generator app on my phone (through the powerful speakers.) The same kind of thing happens when I play other pure frequencies.

The speakers are pretty high quality, so I don't think its any artifacts created by them (but correct me if I'm wrong.) Clearly it isn't aliasing, since the audio data sampling rate is controlled by the teensy ([correct me if I'm wrong](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/gui/index.html?info=AudioInputI2S)).

I figure it must be artifacts because the sound is bouncing off the walls, but I don't see how that could result in such specific overtones. I would just expect to have a bunch of slightly delayed copies of the same signal, and delaying a signal just results in scaling the entire Fourier transform by a constant. I don't see how this could change a purely-263Hz signal to a mostly-263Hz-partially-777Hz signal.

I found a post on some forum talking about something kind of similar, but the replies were not very helpful. Does anyone have any idea where these overtones might be coming from?

Comment: Harmonic distortion is not uncommon, especially in systems with design issues creating any sort of *non-linearity*.  It's unclear how well your audio capture and analysis really works, but you could try a cross comparison to comparable analysis on a PC or phone.  Also note that in comparison to a sine generator, musical tones are often heavy with and characterized by their overtones.   Questions here need to be supported by enough specific detail to be answerable - so for this to survive you'll likely need to provide not only the output data, but detail design of your system.

Comment: Most likely you're looking at some clipping distortion - your powerful speakers may be driving the microphone too hard. Hard clipping of a sine wave approaches a square wave, which consists of odd harmonics: frequency f, 3f, 5f..., and 777hz is about 3 times 263 hz. Try lowering the volume; you may see the 777hz bin drop more rapidly than the 263hz bin.

Comment: Have you tried putting the mic closer to the speaker at lower volume? For my FFT setup, I use a phone sine wave app and a Bluetooth speaker very close to my mic with reasonable success.